# Find the value of $\left((\log_29)^2\right)^{1/\log_2(\log_29) }\times \left(\sqrt{7}\right)^{1/\log_47}$

Tags: logarithms

The value of$\left((\log_29)^2\right)^{1/\log_2(\log_29) }\times \left(\sqrt{7}\right)^{1/\log_47}$.

My approach :

I am able to solve this part : $(\sqrt{7})^{1/\log_47}$ by changing base :

$(\sqrt{7})^{1/\log_47}   =  (7)^{2\log_74} = 16$

But I am unable to figure how to solve this part :

$\Bigl((\log_29)^2\Bigr)^{1/\log_2(\log_29)}  $

Please help on this … thanks

Comment: Please [don't use `\frac` in exponents or limits of integrals](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5057/290189). It looks bad and confusing, and it rarely appears in professional mathematics typesetting.

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to [make it take up less vertical space](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions.  See [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730/290189) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: let $\log_29=x$

Comment: Have you plugged it into WolframAlpha yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first part is incorrect. $$(\sqrt{7})^{1/\log_47}   =  (7^{1/2})^{\log_74} = 2$$
Use @00xxqhxx00's hint to solve for the 2nd part.  Let $x = \log_29$ $$\Bigl((\log_29)^2\Bigr)^{1/\log_2(\log_29)} = (x^2)^{1/\log_2 x} = (x^2)^{\log_x 2} = 4$$
Hence the required product is $2 \times 4 = 8$.

Comment: Thanks a lot God bless you... its great... sorry for the mistake which i done.. thanks once again.

Answer (score 2):

There's a mistake.

$\begin{align}\sqrt7 ^ {\log_74} = 7^{\frac12\log_74} = 4^\frac12 = 2\end{align}$

Let $\log_29 = k$

So we have $(k^2)^{1/\log_2k} = 2^ 2 = 4$

Answer (score 1):

An important relation is : $$\log_a b= \frac{1}{\log_b a}$$
And,
$$a^{\log_a b}=b$$

Your question:$$ \Bigl((\log_2 9 * \log_2 9)^{\frac{1}{\log_2 (\log_2 9)}} \Bigr)* 7^{\frac{1}{2* \log_4 7}} $$
Can be written as:
$$\Bigl((\log_2 9)^{\log_{\log_2 9}2}\Bigr)^{2} * \bigl(7^{\frac{\log_7 4}{2}}\bigr)$$
$$(2)^{2}*{2}=8$$

Hence, the answer is 8, using the above mentioned relations.